# How to unjar, and edit source and jar it back using maven?

Tags: java, maven, package, unpack

I have a situation where i need to Unpack a spring jar and replace a file in that package with my .class file and repackage it back as jar. I understood that this can be done in Maven. So i created a maven project and i added the .java(to be replace in the Spring jar) to it . Here is my Project structure.

[image]

here is my `pom.xml`

```
    <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>repackage</name>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>    
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
    <!-- Unpacking -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Packing -->
<!--      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <classesDirectory>target</classesDirectory>
                        <classifier>sample</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>-->
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am able to unpack the spring jar using `maven dependency plugin` and i figured out how to pack it back to a jar using `maven-jar-plugin`. The part i am struggling to understand 1) how convert my .java file into a .class file. As the packaging is pom type `<packaging>pom</packaging>` I am not able to compile the java file(`JdkVersion.java`). if successful in creating the class file 2) How to replace this .class file into unpacked spring jar as the file i need to replace is inside the sub directory of `/spring`package

Comment: Best is to create a usual java project where your JdkVersion file can be compiled and use the maven-shade-plugin to filter/replace/add the resulting .class file to the finals shaded jar...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. Spring is an open source project just clone its source code https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework?files=1 and update the code and create a package using simple mvn package command

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't see the Version of the spring we are using which is 2.5.6 in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Sarfaraz, It still don't have the version we are using which is spring 2.5.6.SECO3. But I am keeping this option open. First i want to figure out using Maven bcoz that's what my team want to try first

Comment: @pushya are you a able to compile your java class?

Comment: to replace the class file you can use the following command  jar uf jar-file input-file(s)  
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Comment: NO i am not able to compile the java class packaging a `<pom>` type.

Comment: How can i use this command `jar uf jar-file input-file(s)` in maven? While hacking for solution i used to jar in command line

Comment: you already have packing and unpacking plugin in your pom just put a maven compiler plugin before  maven-jar-plugin
  `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin> `
this will solve the issue

Comment: i tried putting the compiler plugin in between packing/unpacking did not compile the java  file

Comment: the pic of your project that you have given does not shows it as java project make it a java project rt click on the project -> click properties -> click Project facets and select java